# Flexbox margin and offseting issue with stair effect

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with a layout I'm trying to achieve with flexbox. I'd like to offset my columns a little more than the previous one to have a diagonal/stairs effect, but I'd also like them to keep the same height grown to the tallest one as flexbox automagically provides.

At first, I thought to myself: I just need to make them the same height with flexbox and then offset them with margins, but it seems that vertical margins are handled quite differently with flexbox as they push the upper side of the box, but not the whole box... this results in all my columns having their bottoms aligned, but that's not what I'd like to achieve.

Note : I know this can be achieved many other ways like relative positioning, adding padding on the parent, setting a min-height, with JavaScript and others, but I'd like to keep the document flow intact, keep ignoring the object's sizes and avoid using JS. I've also read that an upcoming flex-gap or item-gap would probably solve such issues in the future, but [it's still an open issue / idea in the CSS Working Group draft](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/592).

Here's a text doodle for documentation's perennity.

```
Flex               Expected
-                  -
|    -             |    -
|    |    -        |    |    -
|    |    |        |    |    |
-    -    -        -    |    |
                        -    |
                             -
```

Here's a live demo of what I want to achieve and the current result with flexbox spec :

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.box{
  flex:0 0 33%;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.box:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.box:nth-child(3){
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.box-inner{
  height: 100%;
  
  text-align:center;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.wrap2{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box2{
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.box2:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.box2:nth-child(3){
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.box-inner2{
  min-height:300px;
  
  text-align:center;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Flexbox</h2>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam eos molestias dicta nemo, accusantium, mollitia iste hic numquam dolorum vero!</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perferendis.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, placeat?</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Expected</h2>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box-inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam eos molestias dicta nemo, accusantium, mollitia iste hic numquam dolorum vero!</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box-inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perferendis.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box-inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, placeat?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Play with bottom margin. See below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-bottom: -120px;
}

.box-inner {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrap2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.box2:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.box2:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.box-inner2 {
  min-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Flexbox</h2>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam eos molestias dicta nemo, accusantium, mollitia iste hic numquam dolorum vero!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perferendis.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, placeat?</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Expected</h2>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box-inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam eos molestias dicta nemo, accusantium, mollitia iste hic numquam dolorum vero!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box-inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perferendis.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box-inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, placeat?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That could be a solution, but as mentionned up there, I want to preserve the natural document flow and this solution offsets the content of the container out of its bounds (in this particular example, it doesn't cause any vosia; problem, but if our .wrap and .wrap2 had background-colors declared, we would see the columns overflowing their containers).

Comment: @DavidLapointe, on ".wrap" just add "padding-bottom: 120px"(top margin distance of the last .box child). This will solve the background color problem, as well as the distance of the next element beneath.

Comment: @Marian07 The fact is that there is an unknown number of columns side by side, so without JavaScript to count the number of columns, I can't use the padding-bottom solution.